# Looping & Renaming #Temp table columns

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

I've got a #TempTble which looks like this:

```
Col1,Col2,5,8,19,....
```

Also, I have another table with description that matches the keys in #TempTble:

```
key   Descr    
===   ====    
5     Descr1    
8     Descr2    
19    Descr3
```

Which is the best way to loop through the #TempTble and rename its columns with the matching descriptions so it looks like this:

```
Col1,Col2,Descr1,Descr2,Descr3,...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the temp table have one column with values 5, 8, 19?  Or does it have columns named 5, 8, 19?

Comment: Do you really need to rename them? You can use a column alias when you query the table instead.

Comment: @Mikael - Unless the temp table columns are fixed that would still need dynamic SQL so wouldn't necessarily be any more convenient. One place where they might not be fixed would be if the temp table was created by doing a `SELECT INTO .. #temp` from a CSV file provided by a third party. I'm assuming something like that may well be the case as otherwise it would of course be best to simply create the table with the desired column names upfront!

Comment: Hi all, I'm trying to amend column headers and not the values.  Thanks.

Comment: Why not simply create the temp table with the column headers you want before you insert the data into it?

Comment: @Walid - I deleted my answer as I'm assuming that the column names come from a third party source in which case you should use a bog standard loop for this rather than string concatenation. That will allow you to call `EXECUTE sp_rename ` in a parameterised way and avoid any possible SQL injection issues.

Comment: I don't know in advance how many columns in my temp table as I'm pivoting data in my stored procedure which depends on the user criteria.

Comment: Also, due to the 8000 varchar max I'm having to use key codes as column headers instead of meaningful descriptions, that's why after my table is populated I need to loop through all column headers and rename them with the matching descriptions.

Comment: So really my questions is: Which is the best way to loop through a table, which I don't know how many columns it contains in advance, and rename the columns using a 2nd table which contains all the descriptions.

Note: My 2nd table contains all the possible keys and the matching descriptions.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IF object_id('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp

declare @map table ([key] sysname,Descr sysname)

INSERT INTO @map
select 5,'Descr1' UNION ALL
select 8,'Descr2' UNION ALL    
select 19,'Descr3'

create table #Temp ([Col1] int,[Col2] int,[5] int,[8] int,[19] int)

DECLARE @name nvarchar(1035), @descr sysname;

DECLARE ColumnCursor CURSOR 
LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY STATIC READ_ONLY TYPE_WARNING
FOR SELECT 'tempdb..#Temp.' + QUOTENAME(name), Descr
FROM tempdb.sys.columns 
JOIN @map m ON m.[key]=name
where object_id=object_id('tempdb..#Temp');

OPEN ColumnCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM ColumnCursor INTO @name, @descr;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN;
 EXECUTE tempdb..sp_rename @name, @descr,'COLUMN';
FETCH NEXT FROM ColumnCursor INTO @name, @descr;
END;
CLOSE ColumnCursor;
DEALLOCATE ColumnCursor;

SELECT * FROM #Temp
```

Comment: +1 there's QUOTENAME again ;). Any reason why you provide a quote_character with `Descr` but not with `name`?

Comment: @Lieven - I deleted the original answer as testing with column names containing `'` or `]` I still wasn't convinced I had got it right.

Comment: @Martin thanks for your help.  Your code works beautifully.  I have 1 question though:  If I select the code and run it, it works fine.  But if I create a sproc and try to execute it I get the the following error: "Msg 15248, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 213
Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong."

Comment: @Martin- Also I'm getting this error if I put in a sproc:"a USE database statement is not allowed in a procedure, function or trigger."

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad design
One option is to run this code;copy the result and run it again

```
select 'exec tempdb..sp_rename ''#temp.['+t1.name+']'','''+t2.descrip+'''' 
from tempdb..syscolumns as t1 inner join mytable as t2 on t1.name=t2.[key] 
where id=OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') and t1.name like '[0-9]%'
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and it does work.  How can I run it dynamically in my stored procedure?

Comment: Like my deleted answer this is vulnerable to SQL injection. Safer to just use a `while` loop or cursor here.